# Prove that $X_1\cup X_2$ is path connected if and only if both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are path connected

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, path-connected

Suppose $X_1\subset [0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$ and $X_2\subset (-\infty,0]\times\mathbb{R}$ such that $X_1\cap X_2=\{0\}\times[0,1]$.
Prove that $X_1\cup X_2$ is path connected if and only if both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are path connected and non-disjoint.

This was a question that was posed on a previous exam, and I know that it is FALSE after talking to several people. (There is a counter example in the comments.) I know that the statement SHOULD say something about being compact, but I am not sure where it is needed. Given the above statement I know how to do if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are path connected then $X_1\cup X_2$ is path connected, but not the other direction.

I am studying for the next exam and any help about what the statement SHOULD say, and how to prove it would be helpful.

Comment: In case anyone is not clear on why this is false, consider $X_1 = \{0\} \times ([0, 1] \cup [2, 3])$ and $X_2 = \{0\} \times [0, 3)$.

Comment: Note, this will not hold if the spaces are disjoint.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame, it was already given that they are not disjoint in the given spaces for $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: The union of two intersecting path-connected subspaces is path-connected. This is rather easy to show. If the union is path-connected, the sets need not themselves be even connected, even if they intersect.

Comment: @MarkSaving: I don't think your example meets the. requirement that $X_1 \cap X_2= \{0\} \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma From the question: "I know how to do if X1 and X2 are path connected then X1∪X2 is path connected, but not the other direction."

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I think $X_2$ should be $\{0\}\times[0,2)$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I agree that showing that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are path connected that $X_1\cup X_2$ is path connected is rather simple. That is not the part that I am having a problem with. There is a counter example for the other direction.

Comment: @podiki: yes, that works. Perhaps, you or Mark could write the corrected version up as an answer.

Comment: @RobArthan The OP knows the statement is false, they are looking for a way to strengthen the hypotheses that makes it true.

Comment: @podiki: I see what you mean. I think it is enough to assume that the $X_i$ are both closed, because then any path from $X_1$ to $X_2$ must pass through $X_1 \cap X_2$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yeah, I meant to say $\{0\} \times [0, 2)$ but it's too late to edit it now.

Comment: @RobArthan Why would a path have to pass through $X_1\cap X_2$?

Comment: Why not just take $X_1 = \{1\},$ and $X_2= \{2\},$ both as subsets of $\Bbb{R}.$ Both $X_1,$ and $X_2$ are path connected, but their union is obviously disconnected.

Comment: @Chickenmancer it does not meet the require requirement that $X_1\cap X_2=\{0\}\times[0,1]$.

Comment: I have written up an answer that (I believe) shows the statement is true if we assume the $X_i$ are both closed.

Comment: Thanks @Killaspe, I didn't see that at the time of writing. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic part is to show that if $X_1 \cup X_2$ is path-connected then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also path-connected. As examples given in the comments show, this is not true in general, but it is true, if we assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both closed. I'll sketch a proof leaving you to fill in some of the details. Let me know if it's unclear.

Assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are closed subsets of any topological space, that $X_1 \cup X_2$ is pathi-connected and that $X_1 \cap X_2$ is non-empty and path-connected. We want to show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both path-connected. By symmetry, it is enough to show that $X_1$ is path-connected.

**Claim**: any path $\alpha : [0, 1] \to X_1 \cup X_2$ from a point $a \in X_1$ to a point $b \in X_2$ has an initial segment contained in $X_1$ that ends in $X_1 \cap X_2$.

To see this, note that if $a$ or $b$ is in $X_1 \cap X_2$, the claim is clear, so I may assume that $a \not\in X_2 $ and $b \not\in X_1$. Now consider the set $T \subseteq [0, 1]$ comprising all $t$ such that for all $s < t$, $\alpha(s) \in X_1 \setminus X_2$ . Let $u = \sup\,T$. Then $\alpha(u) \in X_1$, because $X_1$ is closed. Moreover, every neighbourhood of $\alpha(u)$ contains a point in $X_2$. So as $X_2$ is closed $\alpha(u) \in X_2$. So the initial segment $\alpha[T]$ of our path $\alpha$ is contained in $X_1$ and ends in $X_1\cap X_2$, as claimed.

Now given $a, b \in X_1$, we need to find a path from $a$ to $b$. To do this, pick $c \in X_2$ and choose paths $\alpha$ from $a$ to $c$ and $\beta$ from $c$ to $b$ (as we may since $X_1 \cup X_2$ is path-connected). Using the claim, we get paths contained in $X_1$ from $a$ and $b$ to points in $X_1 \cap X_2$, and, as the latter is path-connected, that gives us a path contained in $X_1$ from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Thanks! I remembered that the professor said something about using compactness for it, and didn't even think about other hypothesis that would have given the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the first answer.
If a path is from $X_1$ to $X_2$ it will cross ${0} \times [0, 1]$. We can take first cross and we have a path from $X_1$ to ${0} \times [0, 1]$ in $X_1$.
Consider two points $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ in $X_1$ then $(a, b), (c, d) \in X_1 \cup X_2$ which is path connected. There exists a path from $(a, b)$ to $(c, d)$ in $X_1 \cup X_2$.

If the path is in $X_1$ it's OK.

If not, the path will pass by a point $(x, y) \in X_2$.
From $(a, b)$ to $(x, y)$ the path will cross ${0} \times [0, 1]$ in a point $(u, v)$. This path is in $X_1$.
From $(x, y)$ to $(c, d)$ the path will cross ${0} \times [0, 1]$ in a point $(w, z)$. This path is in $X_1$.
We can now take the path from $(a, b)$ to $(u, v)$ and from $(u, v)$ to $(w, z)$ in ${0} \times [0, 1] \subset X_1$ and from $(w, z)$ to $(c, d)$. It's a path from $(a, b)$ to $(c, d)$ in $X_1$.
$X_1$ is then path connected.

Comment: I believe that this is still not true, since it doesn't use additional hypothesis....and we know that the original statement is false from counter examples.

Comment: i mad a mistake. a path from $X_1$ to $X_2$ will not necessarily pass by ${0} \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to see if helps you see where you were making unjustified assumptions. Also a tip about using MSE: if you get an answer wrong and then delete it, you can edit it and undelete it.